# Difference between UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects and UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute - Status Code Pages in Asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using UseStatusCodePages Middleware to show status code pages on my application but it shows plain text on UI without any other information,

I want to show UI with Status Code Information along with some other helpful information like Customer Support Number with more user-friendly page.

I found out we can use two extension methods to do that which is UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects and UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute. Only Difference I found out from [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.0#configuring-status-code-pages) is,

**UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects** : Send 302 to Client.

**UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute** : Send Original Status Code and Executes handler for redirect URL.

Is that the only difference?

Comment: Take a look for yourself by examining the source in [StatusCodePagesExtensions](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/4e044a1e30454b87edbc316f40ba608d1160cb28/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/StatusCodePage/StatusCodePagesExtensions.cs) class.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the  main difference is that  UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects  is redirecting you to error controller action method while UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute  is just rendering page with out redirecting

**Example**

Controller actions

```
[Route("error/404")]
public IActionResult Error404(int code)
{

    return View("Error404");
}
[Route("error/{code}")]
public IActionResult Error(int code)
{
    return StatusCode(code);
}
```

Startup  Cinfigue

```
 app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/error/{0}");
```

or

```
  app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");
```

**Case 1 (404 Error)**

Url : https://localhost:5001/notexits_page

1) ***UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects***
*Result*:

Url is: https://localhost:5001/error/404

We see Error404 page

2) ***UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute***

*Result*:

Url is: https://localhost:5001/notexits_page

We see Error404 page

**Case2 (401 Error)**

Url : https://localhost:5001/admin/users

1) ***UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects***
*Result*:

Url is: https://localhost:5001/error/401

We stack in infinity loop

1) ***UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects***
*Result*:

Url is: https://localhost:5001/admin/users

We see default browser error page for 401 error

Comment: The deleted answer is correct, they both cause 302, not sure which use when.

Answer (score 2):

**When Using app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/Error/{0}") and invalid request(lets say "/abc/xyz") is raised then**;

- Status Code 404 is issued, app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/Error/{0}")  intercepts the request and 302 status code is issued(which means URI of the requested resource has been changed temporarily)
- As 302 is issued another get request is issued which results in *change of the url from
  "/abc/xyz" to "/Error/404".*
- As the request is redirected to the specific error controller the *status code for the request is 200 ok in the browser developer tool*.

**But When Using app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}") and invalid request(lets say "/abc/xyz") is raised then;**

- app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}") middleware intercepts the 404 status code and re-executes the pipeline pointing it to the URL
- As the middleware is re executing the pipeline the original URL "/abc/xyz" in the address bar is preserved. It does not change from "/abc/xyz" to "/Error/{0}".
- *Also the original status Code(404 in this case) is preserved in the developer tool*.